# What else is considered a heavy task in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, background-process

Heavy tasks in Android should be executed in background threads. Heavy tasks are:

- database tasks
- work with images, audio, video
- fetching and parsing internet data
- some extensive calculations (very rare in most apps)

What else can be considered as a heavy task and should be executed in background thread?

I am getting an ANR error and I need to know which tasks Android interprets as heavy tasks.

Comment: Whatever your application is doing when it gets the error.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am not sure. Users report this. But the main purpose is to understand if some other tasks are considered heavy ones.

Comment: Try to find the heavy task with help of the LogCat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What else can be considered as a heavy task and should be executed in background thread?

If it takes more than couple of milliseconds, it should be executed in a background thread.

Courtesy of Project Butter in Android 4.1, the Android UI now updates at 60fps, meaning that there is ~16ms to do everything that is needed to render a frame. The OS needs some of that time to do the actual rendering. If you take more than a few milliseconds, you may skip a frame, causing "janky" behavior. Even on earlier versions of Android, the effect can be seen -- it's just going to be more jarring on Jelly Bean, because everything else is smoother.

Comment: how do you suggest that I measure the execution time of each component? any sdk tool for this?

Comment: @sandalone: You can use everything from simple `Log` statements to [`TimingLogger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html) to [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)

Answer (score 3):

The system doesn't throw up the ANR because it notices that you're doing something that it categorizes as "heavy"; it produces the ANR because the user interface is unresponsive. Using debug statements (i.e., Log.d()) you need to track the progress of your app and figure out what it's doing (or trying to do) when you get your error. For example, an infinite loop on the UI thread would produce an ANR, but there's (provably) no way to categorize any arbitrary loop as infinite or not.